# How to print the version of r in bash chunk?

Tags: r, bash

I need to print my r version in a bash chunk in an r markdown file. In my terminal, I can print the version using "R --version" but when I try that command in bash I get the following error "R: command not found." When I use commands like git --version in the bash shell it works normally. Does anyone have any idea why the R --version code is different?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably it is because in the other environment, the place where the R binary is, is missing from `$PATH`. Can you check, in the one where it works what `which R` says_ And then, in the other environment, can you check if that _directory_ is included in `$PATH` (with `echo $PATH`)? (Welcome to SO).

Comment: It sounds like R isn't in your PATH environment variable. Can you open R from the command line by just typing R? Is bash your default shell or do you use a different shell interactively vs the script?

Comment: Yes, R is in the path. It opens in the command line when I type R and it is included in the echo $PATH output.

Comment: Another interested point - R --version works in my bash shell, just not in the bash chunk of the R Markdown file

Comment: In the shell where it works, say `type R`, that will show you what that environment thinks `R` is. If it gives you a path, replace `R` in your markdown file with that path, otherwise add the `type` output to your question..

Comment: Alright, type R gave me a path, which was the same as the directory in my path environment variables. But replacing R with that path in the markdown file resulted in "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: Perhaps in the bash script, you've *altered* the PATH setting somehow. Observe it before attempting to run `R --version`.

Answer (score 0):

```
R -e 'cat(sessionInfo()$R.version$version.string, "\n")'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try this:

`$(type R | grep -o '/.*') --version`

`type` will get you to the correct R version, `grep` will extract the path, and then you can pass the `--version` flag to get the R chunk.

Terminal output:

```
$ $(type R | grep -o '/.*') --version
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- "Camp Pontanezen"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```